# How to change background color of a section in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to change the background color of a section in a collection view. I've seen a few answers here but they are several years old and involve creating decoration views that stretch the entire size of the section.

Is there a modern approach for this functionality or is this the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can check and try this tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/

Answer (score 0):

This is not the only possible approach, but definitely one of the most obvious ones. The only (sub)views (apart from the scroll indicators) a collection view has is itself and your cells/decoration views. As such, there is nothing that clearly defines a region of the screen that belongs to a section that you could "paint" onto.

Moreover, because layouts can be customized however you like, it's also possible that your section may have gaps or some other peculiar shape that is not easy to infer — tl;dr: the collection view doesn't know how to paint backgrounds of sections. You will need to do it yourself: either by inserting a decoration view which spans over the whole region of your section or by other means, perhaps implementing `draw()` on some special view.